# Calculate 6 business days

Tags: python, python-2.x, datetime

I wrote a little class that will calculate 6 business days from today. The reason it's in a class is because it will be used as a part of a bigger program.

I would like a way to refactor this class and make it a little more object oriented along with a little prettier.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class BusinessDay(object):
    """
    Calculate a business day of 6 days skipping Saturday and Sunday
    """
    return_date = []  # Array to store the calculated day

    def __init__(self, start_day):
        """
        :type start_day: Object, datetime object
        """
        self.start_day = start_day

    def calc_bus_day(self):
        """Calculate 6 business days from the self.start_day example:
        >>> import BusinessDay
        >>> test = BusinessDay(datetime(2016, 9, 14))
        >>> test.calc_bus_day()
        >>> #2016-09-22
        """
        days_skipped = self.start_day + timedelta(8)

        if datetime.isoweekday(days_skipped) in range(2, 6):
            print("Date {} is a weekday.".format(self.start_day))
            self.return_date = days_skipped
            print("Six days from today will be {}".format(self.return_date))
        else:
            print("Date {} is a weekend.".format(self.start_day))
            self.return_date = days_skipped + timedelta(2)
            print("Six days from the weekend will be {}".format(self.return_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")))

        if self.return_date.isoweekday() is 1 or 7:
            if self.return_date == 1:
                self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(2)
                return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
            else:
                self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(1)
                return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
```

Comment: Why would you want to make this code object-oriented? What are the objects here, the classes? What do they add? This code should be a single function. Don't just blindly try to make code OO; try to make code the best it can be, and use whatever tools are necessary to achieve that.

Comment: @gardenhead It's going to be apart of a much bigger program, and this is just the first section of this class.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question though. Large program =/= make everything an object. If you're structuring a large project, the primary concern is modularity, and you have to carefully think about how you're going to structure your code to achieve that modularity. In this case, a vanilla function (either grouped with similar functionality in a module or by itself) is the clearest way to go.

Comment: @gardenhead I was thinking about this last night, and I agree with you, I'm going to move this into a different class with a bunch of other `settings` type functions

Answer (score 7):

#### Bug

```
if self.return_date.isoweekday() is 1 or 7:
```

Is always true because `7` is true, adding parenthesis will help you understand:

```
 if  ( self.return_date.isoweekday() is 1 ) or 7:
```

To get proper behaviour use:

```
 if self.return_date.isoweekday() in (1, 7):
```

#### Repetition

```
self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(2) 
return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
```

And:

```
self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(1) 
return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
```

Use a if/ternary for the first `timedelta` arguments and flatten these lines.

#### No class

You have a single function with a single argument, simplify and avoid a class. (You can re-use your function without a class, just put it in a separate module and `import` it.)

Comment: Amen. Don't overbuild stuff just because you think OO is cool 'cause everyone says it is. Great answer, I would just add that instead of worrying about how pretty the code is, maybe they should of written tests to see that they have a major bug in it like the one you found.

Comment: @Idog this is only the first section of this class, took me forever to figure this out and I wanted some input, I do agree that it's a bit over complicated. I did test it, that's why I posted it, but this is really my first _real_ program in Python, so you know, I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing lol.

Comment: @Caridorc can't believe I didn't catch the bug, I thought I had this perfect lol. Thank you for the answer and the input, much appreciated, like always.

Answer (score 2):

**a look at the code**

```
    days_skipped = self.start_day + timedelta(8)
```

I might rename this variable. The code just skipped eight days, it might end up on an `end_day`, or something like that? (Might want to comment that its eight because there must be a weekend within those six days. This is still pretty clear, but it will get less straightforward if you ever allow for variable skips.)

```
    if datetime.isoweekday(days_skipped) in range(2, 6):
        print("Date {} is a weekday.".format(self.start_day))
        self.return_date = days_skipped
        print("Six days from today will be {}".format(self.return_date))
```

This is a bit confusing, since you're testing the date 8 days from now, but printing what the current day is. Why not just test if the starting day is from Monday to Friday, if that's what you mean: `1 <= datetime.isoweekday(self.start_day) <= 5`. Also, `in range(2,6)` is True for values 2,3,4 and 5, but *not* for 6, which is probably not what you want.

```
    else:
        print("Date {} is a weekend.".format(self.start_day))
        self.return_date = days_skipped + timedelta(2)
        print("Six days from the weekend will be {}".format(self.return_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")))
```

Also, if this is supposed to skip to the start of the week in case the starting day falls on Sat or Sun, I think you should skip ahead either 1 or 2 days depending on which one it is, instead of always skipping 2.

```
    if self.return_date.isoweekday() is 1 or 7:
```

Like @Caridorc wrote in their answer, this is always true. But even you meant `self.return_date.isoweekday() in (1, 7)`, why are Monday and Sunday special cases here?

```
        if self.return_date == 1:
```

I don't think this will ever hold. I guess you meant`self.return_date.isoweekday() == 1`

```
            self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(2)
            return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
```

This adds two, then subtracts two. Confusing, and no effect.

```
        else:
            self.return_date = self.return_date + timedelta(1)
            return self.return_date - timedelta(2)
```

Again, add one, subtract two? Wouldn't it be simpler to just subtract one?
But if this subtraction runs on Sunday, you'd end up on a Saturday, right?

Should you `return` something after the final `if`? Now it only returns anything if the test for 1 or 7 matches.

**algorithm**

Actually, I can't understand your algorithm from this code, so I can't say if it's correct. Mostly because of the confusing conditionals. I would approach something like this by writing the logic down, in some human language if necessary, and then implement that.

(Actually, skipping a fixed number of days is almost painfully simple, since it'll always go from a known weekday to another known weekday. 
Mon->Tue, Tue->Wed, Wed->Thu, Thu->Fri, Fri,Sat or Sun->Mon, so 8,8,8,8,10,9 or 8 days ahead, depending on the starting weekday.)

**structure**

I think this could be condensed to a single function. Preferably one that would take the starting date and number of days to skip. Even if you need a larger class around it, it would be easy to just drop the function in as a utility.

Comment: 6 is Saturday, so `2,6` is exactly what I want

Comment: @YoYo, mmh, If the starting date is a Friday, then 8 days ahead is a Saturday, which will not match the `range`, and the code will print `Date 2016-09-16 00:00:00 is a weekend.`. But it's not, it's a Friday. (It'll print "is a weekend" for Fri, Sat and Sun)